# CSS: Center image link inside a table row

Tags: html, css

I need help to center a link with background image inside a table cell.

```css
tr.match td.oddsselected {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.oddsselected a {
  background: skyblue url(../../img/odds.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 28px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  width: 60px;
  color: #fff;
}
.oddsselected a:hover {
  background: limegreen url(../../img/hodds.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="oddsselected"><a href="#" target="_blank" title="Click">value</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There is a reason we have things like jsfiddle.net and the code-snippet function on this page. Make a working example, please.

Comment: Yeah build a demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `a` is displaying as a block element, you'll need to set the alignment rules for the text on that.

```css
tr.match td.oddsselected {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.oddsselected a {
  background: skyblue url(../../img/odds.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  display: block;
 
  /* horizontally centers the text */
  text-align: center;

  /* vertically centers it - 28px height - 8px top padding = 20px */
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 28px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  width: 60px;
  color: #fff;
}
.oddsselected a:hover {
  background: limegreen url(../../img/hodds.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="oddsselected"><a href="#" target="_blank" title="Click">value</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that only uses padding for the same effect. It also does away with the 'px' measurements, which shouldn't be used on the web except for a few very specific cases.

```css
tr.match td.oddsselected {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;

}
.oddsselected a {
  background: skyblue url(../../img/odds.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  display: block;
 
  /* horizontally centers the text */
  text-align: center;

  /* vertically centers it - 28px height - 8px top padding = 20px */
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}
.oddsselected a:hover {
  background: limegreen url(../../img/hodds.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="oddsselected"><a href="#" target="_blank" title="Click">value</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```